# Javascript position an image over another

Tags: javascript, image

I have the below source and what I want to do is have an image appear if a certain code is entered.  The trick is that I need the image to be on top of another image.  Any way to do this?

```
var roomCode = prompt("Please enter the room code", "Enter room code here");
        if(roomCode==='102')
        {
            /*I want the image to appear at certain coordinates (on top of another image).*/
        }
```

Comment: What about replacing the previous image?

Comment: @derek_duncan that is a good idea, but how would I accomplish that, as I have the underlying image mapped?

Comment: About to post answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the previous image's `src` attribute with your new image's path.

**Example:**

HTML

```
<img id="replacable-img" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" width="400px" alt="Original image">
<button id="change">Next Image</button> // Just example trigger
```

Javascript

```
var img = document.getElementById('replacable-img');
var button = document.getElementById('change');

change.onclick = function(e) {
  img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/wiredscience/2012/10/kitten-kisses-dog.jpg')
}
```

Just use `element.setAttribute('src', 'PATH')` within each `if` block :)

And here's an example: http://jsbin.com/cefutaqo/1/

Comment: Looks good.  I'll give it a go now and if it works, I'll mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Initially create an html page and even image in it.
Set image display property as none.

try this,

```
var roomCode = prompt("Please enter the room code", "Enter room code here");
        if(roomCode==='102')
        {
              load(roomCode+".html");
              $('.image').css('display',block)
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite follow you.  It seems that you are loading a new webpage, which I don't want to do

Comment: you can even load in particular div in the same page